# Assign input textfield having Javascript Array Value to javascript Array Variable

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to populate some location data for google maps initialization, So to an HTML input field I assign it with an JavaScript array format so that I use it for google maps but all in vein. . . .
Here is my Code

```
      <input id="a" name="a" value='["WAPDA Town, Lahore, Pakistan","31.4311985","74.26435820000006","1"],["Johar Town, Lahore, Pakistan","31.469693","74.27284610000004","2"],'>
```

then I further Call it in my script to initialize it for locations.

```
 var location = '[' + document.getElementById('a').value + ']';
```

but it is not giving my desire result as I know I'm doing wrong. but what is the proper way of initalizing it? Any Suggestion

Comment: use `JSON.parse`. `var location = JSON.parse('[' + document.getElementById('a').value + ']');` (but you need to get rid of the trailing ',' at the end). `document.getElementById('a').value.slice(0, -1)` will remove the trailing ','

Comment: Why are you putting that array in an `<input>` element in the first place?

Comment: @Pointy the input value doesn't have a '[ ]'

Comment: @Pointy input value has multiple array seperated by ','. so we need to wrap the value with '[]'

Comment: @ajaiJothi Answer Worked for me I'm keep searching for this for last two hours save my day :D

Comment: @ajaiJothi oh of course, sorry I did not scroll right far enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (I remove last comma from your input)

```js
var loc = JSON.parse(`[${a.value}]`);

console.log(loc);
```

```html
 <input id="a" name="a" value='["WAPDA Town, Lahore, Pakistan","31.4311985","74.26435820000006","1"],["Johar Town, Lahore, Pakistan","31.469693","74.27284610000004","2"]'>
```

Comment: Thanks This is also a right answer thanks, But why we use JSON.parse while getting array from HTML input field

Comment: @NaveedCheema because the value of an input is always a string.